# Data structure for complex keys in dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, tuples

In case of a Dictionary where the key is complex (a combination of values)
For instance, the key could be a pair of string and integer.

What data type would you recommend to use for the key? I take into account performance and memory usage in case of massive reads from the dictionary, data types that are heavy to allocate would probably not be a good candidate for the task.

I tested 4 different strategies.

1. The most naive one, using a string as key and concat the components:

   ```
   int Read(string str, int num)
   {
       var key = str + "|" + num;
       return dict[key];
   }
   ```
2. Using a tuple for representing the key:

   ```
   int Read(string str, int num)
   {
       var key = new Tuple<string, int>(str, num);
       return dict[key];
   }
   ```
3. Using a KeyValuePair for representing the key:

   ```
   int Read(string str, int num)
   {
       var key = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(str, num);
       return dict[key];
   }
   ```

I don't like the first method much, the one with the tuple seems more elegant.
However, Tuple is not so different than a string in the sense that they are both classes and allocating them can be expensive.
KeyValuePair seemed like the most viable data type but after running some tests i saw that it performs much worse than strings or tuples which now seems obvious to me given that KeyValuePair does not implement GetHashCode().
I then tried to implement my own "KeyValuePair" that overrides Equals and GetHashCode():

```
struct KVPair<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }

    public V Value { get; set; }

    public KVPair(K key, V value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is KVPair<K,V>))
        {
            return false;
        }

        KVPair<K, V> other = (KVPair<K, V>)obj;
        return Key.Equals(other.Key) &&
            Value.Equals(other.Value);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int keyHash = Key.GetHashCode();
        int valHash = Value.GetHashCode();

        return (((keyHash << 5) + keyHash) ^ valHash);
    }
}
```

And use it as a key in my dictionary:

```
    int Read(string str, int num)
    {
        var key = new KVPair<string, int>(str, num);
        return dict[key];
    }
```

It seems to perform better than the string and tuple options and much better than the native KeyValuePair.

I just wanted to hear what would you recommend.
I am always cautious when having to implement my own data types, since the FCL usually takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use especific type with related property names:

```
public class RowKey
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public RowKey()
    {
    }

    public RowKey(string title, int id)
    {
        Title = title;
        Id = id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (!(obj is RowKey))
            return false;

        RowKey other = obj as RowKey;
        return Title.Equals(other.Title) && Id.Equals(other.Id);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int titleHash = Title.GetHashCode();
        int idHash = Id.GetHashCode();

        return (((titleHash << 5) + titleHash) ^ idHash);
    }
}
```

Read using:

```
int Read(string str, int num)
{
    var key = new RowKey(str, num);
    return dict[key];
}
```

Comment: But isn't it the same as using a Tuple? It's a class and my considerations against it are allocations.

Comment: Yes, but, think about your code structure and organization. Tuples are generic and you can lost your context...

Comment: That's a good point against using Tuples in this case. But what about making your key a struct instead of class?

Comment: To your usecase, class can be fastest, see: https://www.dotnetperls.com/struct-versus-class